# Changing mouse cursor on ajaxStart

Tags: css, jquery

I have the following scripts which work fairly nicely:

```
$("#spanLoading").ajaxStart(function () {
    $('#spanLoading').empty().append("<img src='/img/loading.gif' />");
});

$("#spanLoading").ajaxComplete(function () {
    $('#spanLoading').empty();
});
```

Is it possible to change these a little, so instead of loading an image on `ajaxStart`, the mouse cursor changes instead to css cursor `wait`, and then changes back to normal when `ajaxComplete`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by changing the `cursor` property of the `body` element:

```
$("#spanLoading").ajaxStart(function () {
    $('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
});

$("#spanLoading").ajaxComplete(function () {
    $('body').css('cursor', 'auto');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
$('html').css('cursor', 'wait');
```

On `ajaxComplete` you change it back.